# Raw socket not receiving UDP packet

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming, udp, raw-sockets

I wrote an application using raw sockets that creates a UDP packet and sends to a destination. The application is working fine and I even saw the packet sent using Wireshark. Now, I want that packet to be captured by another application on the destination system. I want to be able to access the UDP header on the destination system. So, I created a receiver using raw sockets on dest system. But, I'm not able to receive the packet to my application. I'm able to capture the packet using SOCK_DGRAM socket, but not with raw socket.

I remember reading that raw sockets doesn't have the concept of ports. Can anyone explain me exactly what's going on the dest system, how the demultiplexing at transport layer works and how the protocol field of ip header effects the transport layer functionality?

**Sender code:**

```c
int main(void){

    char message[] = "This is something very useful";

    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP);

    if(sockfd < 0){
        perror("Error creating socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in this, other;

    this.sin_family = AF_INET;
    other.sin_family = AF_INET;

    this.sin_port = htons(9000);
    other.sin_port = htons(8000);

    this.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    other.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&this, sizeof(this)) < 0){
        printf("Bind failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char packet[64];
    memset(packet, 0, 64);

    struct udphdr *udph = (struct udphdr *) packet;
    strcpy(packet + sizeof(struct udphdr), message);

    udph->uh_sport = htons(8080);
    udph->uh_dport = htons(8000);
    udph->uh_ulen = htons(sizeof(struct udphdr) + sizeof(message));
    udph->uh_sum = 0;

    if(sendto(sockfd, packet, sizeof(struct udphdr) + sizeof(message), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &other, sizeof(other)) < 0)
        perror("Error");
    else
        printf("Packet sent successfully\n");

    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

**Receiver code:**

```c
int main(void){

    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP);

    char message[64];

    if(sockfd < 0){
        perror("Error creating socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in this;
    this.sin_family = AF_INET;
    this.sin_port = htons(8000);
    this.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&this, sizeof(this)) < 0){
        printf("Bind failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(recv(sockfd, message, 64, 0) < 0){
        perror("Error");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("\n\n%s\n\n", message);

    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: there are different kind of "raw sockets", depending on the "layer/family" you create them on. If you use AF_PACKET, then you have to handle the Ethernet header (source/dest MAC) as well, then the IP header. In your case, AF_INET and IPPROTO_UDP already designate the layer pretty precisely. Any reasonfor not just using SOCK_DGRAM in your scenario?

Comment: I just wanted to verify the checksum and manually discard the packet if the checksum is not correct. But, I understood that the Operating System handles raw sockets differently.

Comment: Your sender puts checksum 0. The IP stack might do checksum offloading on the card and fill that with a valid one but I doubt it. Do you see a valid checksum in wireshark? If not, it probably is dropped by the receiver before reaching your socket